# Wrapping C++ CLI Class For C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to call some Windows basic functions from C#, in particular [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) one.
Since the moment I want to learn the C++/CLI Language too, I've written down this code:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;

namespace InformazioniSchermo {

    public class Native_InformazioniDaSistema
    {
    public:
        int m_nAltezzaPannello;
        int m_nLarghezzaPannello;

        Native_InformazioniDaSistema(void)
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
            DWORD dev = 0;

            dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
            EnumDisplayDevices(0, dev, &dd, 0);
            m_nAltezzaPannello = 100;
            m_nLarghezzaPannello = 100;
        }
    };

    public ref class InformazioniDaSistema
    {
    public:
        InformazioniDaSistema();
        ~InformazioniDaSistema();

    public:
        int m_nHeight;
        int m_nWidth;
    };

    InformazioniDaSistema::InformazioniDaSistema()
    {
        Native_InformazioniDaSistema foo;

        m_nHeight = foo.m_nAltezzaPannello;
        m_nWidth = foo.m_nLarghezzaPannello;
    }

    InformazioniDaSistema::~InformazioniDaSistema()
    {
    }
}
```

but when I compile, I get this error:

```
Error   3   error LNK2028: at unresolved token (0A0003B4) "extern "C" int __stdcall EnumDisplayDevicesW(wchar_t const *,unsigned long,struct _DISPLAY_DEVICEW *,unsigned long)" (?EnumDisplayDevicesW@@$$J216YGHPB_WKPAU_DISPLAY_DEVICEW@@K@Z) referencing in function "public: __thiscall InformazioniSchermo::Native_InformazioniDaSistema::Native_InformazioniDaSistema(void)" (??0Native_InformazioniDaSistema@InformazioniSchermo@@$$FQAE@XZ)  c:\Users\massimiliano\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\InformazioniSchermo\InformazioniSchermo\InformazioniSchermo.obj InformazioniSchermo
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link against `user32.lib` (the library for the `EnumDisplayDevices` function, as you'll see in the MSDN page you linked to).

You can do this by going to project properties->Linker->Input and adding `user32.lib` to the "Additional Dependencies" list.

I notice that the default Visual Studio project settings for C++/CLI don't include the common Windows API libraries by default (regular C++ projects have `kernel32.lib`, `user32.lib`, `shell32.lib` and others added to the project's library dependencies in new projects) so you have to add these libraries yourself if you're using them.

Answer (score 2):

```
 error LNK2028: ... (?EnumDisplayDevicesW@@$$J216YGHPB_WKPAU_DISPLAY_DEVICEW@@K@Z) ...
```

That is the name the linker is looking for.  That is **not** it's name, it is a C function and does not have the C++ name mangling.  Pretty unclear how you did that, especially since you obfuscated your #includes.  But the only reasonable guess is that you declared this function yourself instead of using its declaration in the SDK header.

Never do that.  Instead use:

```
  #include <Windows.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
```

With the #pragma helpful so you can't forget to link to user32